# Is it possible to configure Dozer such that by default fields are rather accessed directly that through setter-/getter method

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I have to map a complex structure of Java classes which don't expose their fields through set-/get-methods in general (this is given and can't be changed).
So mapping can only be performed on a direct field access. Dozer allows individual fields to be made accessible but I haven't found a setting to make this the general behaviour. As a result I wouldn't have to map each field explicitly just for making it accessible!

Does this option exist?
 - On a class level?
 - On a global level?

Answer (score 8):

You can set it on a class level.

```
<mapping>
   <class-a is-accessible="true">MyClass</class-a>
   ...
</mapping>
```

From the Dozer XSD:

> is-accessible Indicates whether Dozer bypasses getter/setter methods and accesses the field directly. This will typically be set to "false". The default value is "false". If set to "true", the
>           getter/setter methods will NOT be invoked. You would want to set this to "true" if the field is lacking a getter or setter method.